# how can i combine all <style> tag added in head tag in angular app?

Tags: angular, angular16, angular2viewencapsulation

[image]
i have seperate component in my angular app,
the version ofangular is 16
so because of view capsulation emulated ,
angular add  tag for each component in head tag,
this is a problem for SEO
how can i fix this issue and add all style in one css file?

i try to make a component folder in my project and add each component style in this folder then add import all these component styles in one global style file

Comment: Why is it a problem for SEO ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will get those multiple style elements when you have component scoped styling.

If you want to have a single style element, then you'll have to rely a global styling (ie no more `stylesUrl`/`styles` in your component.

That beeing said, there is no strong evidence that multiple style elements will negatively impact SEO.

Comment: Thank you for your response; I myself think that it may not have much impact on SEO, but the SEO team had this request.